# Поворот объекта в pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Я делаю небольшую игру про парковку, и мне надо сделать машину, которая будет относительно реалистично поворачивать, то есть поворот только при езде вперёд или назад. Везде ищу - найти как сделать поворот - не могу. Помогите пожалуйста.
код:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = player_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_w]:
            self.speedy = 10
        if keystate[pygame.K_s]:
            self.speedy = -10
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.speedx = -10
        if keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.speedx = 10
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
```

Если что-то ещё надо, напишите пожалуйста

Comment: Опишите требуемый результат. Сейчас непонятно что вам нужно.

Comment: [pygame движение машинки](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=pygame+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)